# Spring transactional method gets rollback even if exception is catched in non-transactional method or in controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional

I am calling two transactional methods inside try-catch block in a non-transactional method. When exception occurs, i am able to catch the exception and logs it. The first transaction method does not get roll back but the last one does. This behavior is what i currently understand in spring transaction management.

```
public void grab(){
    try{
        requestManager.updateRequest();
        requestManager.saveTicket()
    }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dive) {
       if (dive.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
           LOGGER.error("ConstraintViolationException",dive);
       }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the ConstraintViolationException occurs inside saveTicket() method and the dao inside saveTicket() already rolled back its transaction even before catching the exception(This is what i know), and the first one does not get rolled back because it is in another transaction.(This is the behavior i already know).

I got confused when i used another transactional method which calls those two previews method(updateRequest() and saveTicket()) which gets rolled back even the updateRequest() method when ConstraintViolationException occurs in saveTicket() method even if catching the exception. Here is my code

```
 public void grab(){
    try{
        requestManager.grabRequest();
    }catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dive) {
       if (dive.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
           LOGGER.error("ConstraintViolationException",dive);
       }
    }
 }
```

What i know is, the two methods will join same transaction inside grabRequest() method, But my question is, why do the transaction gets rolled back even if i am catching the exception? Does this mean that the proxy that spring uses already rolled back the transaction even before i catch the exception?

Comment: ?? it is strange that the transaction is rollbacked in the saveTicket() and spring just re-throws the exception?? what would be the expected behavior ? Also i suppose that you havent annotated only the methods with `@Transactional` but the whole class so thats why in the second example with `grabRequest()` it rollbacks both the transactions. Could you post the `requestManager` class along with the 3 mentioned methods

Comment: Thanks for the response. But why is it strange that transaction gets rolled back in the saveTicket? What i know is that the dao won't persist the data because of the exception. So even if i catch the exception, the dao inside saveTicket() already rolled back. Yes the grabRequest() is also transactional that is why it will roll back the whole transaction. But why does spring rolled it back even if it is being catch inside try-catch? is it because of the proxy that spring uses?

Comment: you are catching an exception that is being re-throwed by spring after roll-backing your transaction. If you go inside the method `saveTicket()` and catch there the exception , then the transaction advisor wont work as expected. But still i got confused , what is your actual target ? is there a problem that spring is working as expected ?

Comment: wooh! I think that solves my problem! I just got confused because i am able to catch the exception but still the transaction gets rolled back in 2nd example, I did not know that spring re-throws the exception after rolling back the transaction that allows me to catch the exception. Thanks man!

Comment: !!! no problem , glad it was helpful , but still if you want to perform your own transactions , simply cut off spring and go on programmatically to define your transactions , and in which steps you want to rollback or not , check [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/2014/12/23/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) example , but not quite suggested

Comment: yeah it was helpful! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that the proxy that spring uses already rolled back the transaction even before i catch the exception?

Yes, in JPA/Spring annotation you can specify a list of Exceptions which your transaction manager must rollback or mustn't rollback in the `@Transactional`

> In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. ( Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback). Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method do not result in rollback in the default configuration.

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

For JPA it's `rollbackOn` and `dontRollbackOn`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!